# How to put an image and some text to .doc file via command-line?

Tags: command-line, doc

I am trying to create a file.doc (Microsoft Word Document format) and write some text into it and also, insert an image into it via command shell. I have no idea what or how should I do it.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: First, you need to define what you mean by "a file.doc" - do you mean a file that is compatible with Microsoft's Word document (`.doc`) format? if so, which version?

Comment: yes, I mean Microsoft Word document, version doesnt really matter, lets say the newest one.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`python-docx`](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx) to create MS Word document by creating an intermediate script to handle the shell arguments.

1. Install required libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-pip libxslt1-dev python-lxml
   sudo pip install python-docx
   ```
2. Write the intermediate script and let's name it `docx-gen`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import sys

   from docx import Document
   from docx.shared import Inches


   if __name__=="__main__":
       document = Document()
       document.add_heading(sys.argv[2], 0)
       document.add_paragraph(sys.argv[3])
       document.add_picture(sys.argv[4],width=Inches(6.0))
       document.add_page_break()
       document.save(sys.argv[1])
       sys.exit(0)
   ```
3. Give it the right permissions

   ```
   chmod +x docx-gen
   ```
4. Use it locally

   ```
   ./docx-gen demo.docx "Title" "A paragraph with few words." ~/Pictures/snapshot1.png
   ```

   or copy it to the system bin folder:

   ```
   sudo cp docx-gen /usr/local/bin/
   ```

   then to use it:

   ```
   docx-gen demo.docx "Title" "A paragraph with few words." ~/Pictures/snapshot1.png
   ```

**Reference:**

I just modified its example, see [its official documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

**Notes:**

- The script does not include any input check, just to keep it simple.
- Used fixed width of 6 inches, you may add it to input arguments too.

[image: demo document for python-docx]